# Tuning antennas

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, pcb-antenna

I am working in a biomedical implant. I have to design an antenna for the wireless power transmission. The frequency that I am using is 13.56 MHz. I used some antennas found in some articles but when I test them (just the antennas) I cannot have a good performance in terms of distance and power transmission.

I used a loop antenna that I need to reduce the size until 5 cm diameter. It has to be a very little antenna (ofc, High frequency) for this communication.

Could you help me with this please! I need to know where to start or what am I doing wrong..

Kind regards!

[image: Antennas]
[image: Frequency input]

Comment: Did you confirm both antennas resonate at your working frequency? The first step toward designing a wireless power transfer system is to have both Tx and Rx antenna resonance at source frequency (13.56 MHz in your case)

Comment: They are but slightly. With a 20 MHz it looks to receive more power. However, not enough.

Comment: What power are you using and what range is required?

Comment: I would require a range of less than 50 cm. Not to much. The most important part is the power because it has to cross the head bone.

Comment: 50 cm or 5 cm? What is the power you need? Step 1. (must do) make sure antennas resonate at working frequency, Step 2. Define the distance and   calculate/Simulate, mutual inductance, coil inductances, coil quality factor. Step 3. Optimize the  load resistance for maximum power transfer. (or if the load is fixed, use impedance matching to maximize power transfer ) There can be alternative approaches but first step is mandatory. So start with it.

Comment: 50 cm of distance! Ok, I will start with that. I will start testing the resonant frequency. Thanks!